# Is it ok to call a static function which returns a local static object inside a static function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-methods, static-variables

Here is the code in C++.

```
class A {
private:
    A() {};
    void xx_func() {}
    void yy_func() {}
public:
    ~A() {};
    static A &GetInstance() {
        static A a_ins;
        return a_ins;
    }
    static void func1() {
        A::GetInstance().xx_func();
        // other code
    }
    static void func2() {
        A::GetInstance().yy_func();
        //other code
    }
};
```

The `GetInstance` function returns a local static variable. Is it safe for `func1` and `func2` to call `A::GetInstance()`?

Comment: Yes it's safe. It's a common way to solve the singleton pattern.

Comment: known as meyer singleton

Comment: Even though func1 is in the class A, it is ok to call  the ```GetInstance``` function?  What if the func1 is a non-static member function?

Comment: Yes, it's OK. If `func1` is non static, then you need to provide an instance to call it e.g. `A::GetInstance().func1()` (which is OK too).

Comment: ... though if you provide the instance, no point in calling it internally

Answer (score 3):

This is absolutely fine, and is reasonably idiomatic. Note that when program control reaches

```
static A a_ins;
```

for the first time, the default constructor for `A` is called. All other threads are blocked on this statement until it completes.

`A` destructs some time after the closing brace `}` of `main` is reached.